# Can we bundle other than CSS and JavaScript files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-bundling

I am looking into the bundling features of ASP.NET MVC and my doubt here is, can we bundle only Javascript and CSS files?

Comment: What else do you want to bundle?

Comment: bundling is only for javascript & css files

Comment: may be for .JSON files @ jumpingcode

Comment: What else you want to bundle.. We do bundling for client side files i.e javascripts and css files.. if you doubt to do it for class files, add a namespace to the class files.. 1